# Gradle Sync Failed: Setup Project Failed: Null

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.2

long time I didn't have an issue like that.
Possibly it's related to testing the Preview build on that project.

Currently on stable Android Studio Version 3.2.1 I always get this strange error:
[image]

What I already did:

- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Clean Build
- Test Terminal Build (everything works)
- Import the project from scratch (it's really small so no problems there - same issue)
- Deleted the /Users/myUserName/.gradle/ folder - completely
- Deleted all my Android Studio preferences under: /Users/myUserName/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.2/
- Deleted ".iml" files and ".idea" folder and tried to import the project again
- Updated system Gradle version to latest Gradle (4.10.2)
- Moved the project to some other directory (nearly root level) to just test all possible errors
- Updated / Changed build tools, targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion
- Tried disable and reenable AndroidStudio android support plugin

Basically all efforts were without any improvements.
Still, something must be wrong with the AS setup, because in Terminal builds everything works out perfect.
Other projects still work perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.toCanonicalPath(FileUtil.java:703)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.toCanonicalPath(FileUtil.java:668)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.normalizeRootUrl(PersistentFSImpl.java:1039)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findRoot(PersistentFSImpl.java:970)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findRoot(PersistentFSImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.prepare(VfsImplUtil.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.findFileByPath(VfsImplUtil.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByPath(LocalFileSystemBase.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile(LocalFileSystemBase.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil.findFileByIoFile(VfsUtil.java:210)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getGradleSettingsFile(GradleUtil.java:364)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateSettingsFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateSettingsFile(BuildModelContext.java:111)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.populateWithParentModuleSubProjectsProperties(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.apply.ApplyDslElement.addParsedElement(ApplyDslElement.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslBlockElement.addParsedElement(GradleDslBlockElement.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:488)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$300(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$2.visitApplicationStatement(GroovyDslParser.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:388)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$100(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.process(GroovyDslParser.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.visitMethodCallExpression(GroovyDslParser.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.path.GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.accept(GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementVisitor.visitElement(GroovyPsiElementVisitor.java:18)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:824)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFile.parse(GradleDslFile.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.moduleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:188)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.getParentModuleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.populateWithParentModuleSubProjectsProperties(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.apply.ApplyDslElement.addParsedElement(ApplyDslElement.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslBlockElement.addParsedElement(GradleDslBlockElement.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:488)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$300(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$2.visitApplicationStatement(GroovyDslParser.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:388)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$100(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.process(GroovyDslParser.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.visitMethodCallExpression(GroovyDslParser.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.path.GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.accept(GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementVisitor.visitElement(GroovyPsiElementVisitor.java:18)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:824)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFile.parse(GradleDslFile.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.moduleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:188)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.getParentModuleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.populateWithParentModuleSubProjectsProperties(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.apply.ApplyDslElement.addParsedElement(ApplyDslElement.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslBlockElement.addParsedElement(GradleDslBlockElement.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:488)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$300(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$2.visitApplicationStatement(GroovyDslParser.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:388)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$100(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.process(GroovyDslParser.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.visitMethodCallExpression(GroovyDslParser.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.path.GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.accept(GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementVisitor.visitElement(GroovyPsiElementVisitor.java:18)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:824)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFile.parse(GradleDslFile.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.moduleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:188)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.getParentModuleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.populateWithParentModuleSubProjectsProperties(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.apply.ApplyDslElement.addParsedElement(ApplyDslElement.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslBlockElement.addParsedElement(GradleDslBlockElement.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:488)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$300(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$2.visitApplicationStatement(GroovyDslParser.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:388)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$100(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.process(GroovyDslParser.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.visitMethodCallExpression(GroovyDslParser.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.path.GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.accept(GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementVisitor.visitElement(GroovyPsiElementVisitor.java:18)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:824)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFile.parse(GradleDslFile.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.moduleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:188)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.getParentModuleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.populateWithParentModuleSubProjectsProperties(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.apply.ApplyDslElement.addParsedElement(ApplyDslElement.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslBlockElement.addParsedElement(GradleDslBlockElement.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:488)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$300(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$2.visitApplicationStatement(GroovyDslParser.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:388)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$100(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.process(GroovyDslParser.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$1.visitMethodCallExpression(GroovyDslParser.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.path.GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.accept(GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementVisitor.visitElement(GroovyPsiElementVisitor.java:18)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:824)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFile.parse(GradleDslFile.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.moduleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:188)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleSettingsModelImpl.getParentModuleModel(GradleSettingsModelImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.populateWithParentModuleSubProjectsProperties(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.lambda$parseBuildFile$1(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:897)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModelImpl.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.files.GradleDslFileCache.getOrCreateBuildFile(GradleDslFileCache.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.BuildModelContext.getOrCreateBuildFile(BuildModelContext.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.apply.ApplyDslElement.addParsedElement(ApplyDslElement.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslBlockElement.addParsedElement(GradleDslBlockElement.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:488)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$300(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser$2.visitApplicationStatement(GroovyDslParser.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:388)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.parse(GroovyDslParser.java:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.access$100(GroovyDslParser.java:130)
    at…
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the gradle.properties file in your project? Does it have any content?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska thanks for asking. Yes I have one, only containing "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G"

Comment: Maybe try updating your gradle (the actual gradle, not the plugin) to a newer version?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your additional proposal - tested it (it really was 2.2 systemwide) - also updated to 4.10.2 - unfortunately also no effect.

Comment: Sorry about that, can you file an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533 ?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska thanks for your feedback, I just created: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118342198. Looking forward to see what the outcome will be.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska FYI with a small hint from Google I was able to trace the issue down. We have a fix now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned and analyzed in the Google bug tracking issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118342198

The issue was produced by configuring and **adding a gradle constants file** within a library sub project. That means:

This gradle dependency file was integrated in the top-level gradle file

> appProject/someLibrary/some_constants.gradle

at

> appProject/build.gradle

by

```
apply from: "someLibrary/some_constants.gradle"
```

**Removing this line fixed the sync issue.**

**The overall solution** was to move the *some_constants.gradle* file **to the top level folder** and just import it there directly.

```
apply from: "some_constants.gradle"
```

The interesting part: This sync issue just occurred if there was ONLY a library module within the project. As soon as an app module was also present this issue didn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the issue occurred because I unloaded a module, but forgot to remove the `include:'my_lib'` line from `settings.gradle`. Removing the include fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps to let Android Studio regenerate the `.iml` file.

1. Close your Android Studio.
2. Go to your project root dir and delete the `.iml` file.
3. Open your project again.

Comment: Thanks a lot - Good try, unfortunately didn't resole the sync problem. One "funny" thing: At the end of the sync I see "Sync successful for a short amount of time - less than 1 second" - afterwards it changes to "failed… null"

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this after upgrading to Android Studio **3.3**. The solution for me was to switch to the Beta Channel and download Android Studio **3.4 Beta 3**, which contains the fix for [that bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118342198).

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading Gradle on the build.gradle to a newer version solve the issue.

Under build script on dependencies the Gradle classpath.